# How can I detect data sent through an Angular Subject?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components in Angular that are shown on the same page.
In the first one, I ask the user to select a date, and in the second one I want to display the weather forecast at that date.

Here is the useful code that I have for now:

**event.service.ts**

```
data$:Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
```

**event-update.component.ts** (First component)

```
  sendWeather(): void {
    this.eventService.data$.next(this.editForm.get('startDate')!.value / 1000);
  }
```

**weather-service.component.ts** (Second component)

```
export class WeatherServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  weather!: any;
  shweather = false;
  day!: number;
  selectedDay!: number;

  constructor(
    private eventService: EventService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventService.getWeather().subscribe((res: Object) => (this.weather = res));
  }

  showWeather(): void {
    this.updateWeather()
    this.shweather = !this.shweather;
  }

  updateWeather(): void {
    this.eventService.data$.subscribe(data => this.selectedDay = data);
    this.day = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
      if (this.selectedDay === this.weather.daily[i]!.dt - 43200) {
        this.day = i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works well to get the date to the second component, but if you change the date in the first component, the second only gets updated when the method updateWeather() is called because it is when we get the data from the Subject in the event service.

showWeather() is called when a button is pressed, and I need to calculate the variable 'day' because I use it in the HTML.

So here comes my question: Is there a way for the second component to get notified when the date changes in the first component so that it displays it instantly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this

weather-service.component.ts (Second component)

```
export class WeatherServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  weather!: any;
  shweather = false;
  day!: number;
  selectedDay!: number;

  constructor(
    private eventService: EventService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventService.getWeather().subscribe((res: Object) => (this.weather = res));
    this.eventService.data$.subscribe(data => {
      this.updateWeather(data)
    });
  }

  showWeather(): void {
    this.shweather = !this.shweather;
  }

  updateWeather(data): void {
    this.selectedDay = data
    this.day = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
      if (this.selectedDay === this.weather.daily[i]!.dt - 43200) {
        this.day = i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the following line to ngOnInit()

```
this.eventService.data$.subscribe(data => this.selectedDay = data);
```